# Cannot install libopencv-dev on Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Has anyone else seen this problem? I'm trying to install OpenCV in Ubuntu Xenial LTS.

I've tried to uncomment the deb-src entries in my /etc/apt/sources.list and still not working.

**sudo apt-get -f install libopencv-dev**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopencv-dev : Depends: libopencv-objdetect-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-legacy-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-contrib-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-videostab-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-superres-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-ocl-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcv-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libhighgui-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcvaux-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: `sudo aptitude install libopencv-dev`

When you get a question that asks about resolving the dependencies, you will see (Y/n/q)?. Enter n.

See what the next (Y/n/q) question is. Usually this part downgrades one of the dependencies so that other dependencies can be solved. This worked for me! Hope it does for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

Use aptitude instead of apt-get. It is more intelligent. It not only will handle downgrading conflicting packages for you, but will make a series of recommendations asking you which of many possible suggested working scenarios you would like.

```
sudo aptitude install myNewPackage
```

If you don't have aptitude on your machine yet, get it with

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```